# How to connect Ubuntu 16.04 Workstation to Samsung Smart TV through Screen Mirroring?

Tags: 16.04, display, samsung

Is there an equivalent Linux/Ubuntu procedure to the screen mirroring procedure described in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05FhF2p-WAo) for a Samsung Smart TV with Windows10?

Comment: @N0rbert My question is specific to Screen Mirroring. Author of that question accepted an answer using Chromecasting which is a different technology to Screen mirroring. Also, my question is asking for Ubuntu/Linux equivalent procedures to what was demonstrated in the video, which is not base on Chromecasting. Appreciate you do not treat this as a duplicate question.

Comment: I retracted close vote.

Comment: @SorenA Pls see my comments to Nurbert and kindly do not treat this as a duplicate question. Thanks.